# How relevant are "Requests per second" benchmarks?

Tags: design, web-development, architecture, performance, frameworks

Whenever a new framework is released it is a given that someone somewhere will benchmark it against other available solutions.

One interesting benchmark is the "Requests per second" benchmark. For example look it [this benchmark](http://systemsarchitect.net/performance-benchmark-of-popular-php-frameworks/):
[image]

Now AFAIK Zend framework and Symfony are 2 of the biggest frameworks out there with major companies supporting them. Did the developers make a mistake when designing the framework that resulted in that (relatively) low threshold?

If I'm planning to build a web site/app and expecting (relatively) high traffic, should I pay attention to this benchmark? Will my site/app surely go down at the presented figures?

Simply I'm asking you as a software architect how you would strategically take into account this benchmark when planning a new project.

Answer (score 2):

Just looking at that graph and leaving out the 2 paragraphs below the graph (in the linked article) easily gives a distorted picture. Let me quote from the article:

> I’m not surprised, Slim is the fastest because it’s a micro framework.
>   The Quick Start project didn’t use any templates or layout which
>   obviously contributed to the reading. Zend1 is twice faster than
>   Symfony2 and Zend2 but in my experience the number will quickly go
>   down in a real live setup.
>
> Frameworks should speed up development, performance is a secondary
>   concern. Zend 2 and Symfony2 could do better but it’s not bad. There
>   are ways to improve those numbers on production servers. Don’t
>   reinvent the wheel, learn and use frameworks. There are various
>   options which balance between performance and features.

So what you should do is: pay attention to that remarks. Benchmarks show that a framework executes **that specific benchmark** with a certain performance, and one should be really, really careful when trying to deduce any real-world decisions from them.

Answer (score 1):

A benchmark typically has little relationship with the code that one ends up writing - it is very unusual for them to test anything close to real world cases, partly because by the time you reach a real world situation there are going to be many more things in play than your application framework. There will be bottlenecks in logic, in data access, all over the place.

Also different frameworks are typically for somewhat different things, so it is unusual for a benchmark like "requests per second" to be equally relevant to different frameworks that offer different things. For example the fastest one on the survey linked in the question is a microframework that does relatively little, so you get faster response times, but you're likely to have to write a lot more code to get things done with it.

That doesn't mean they are completely useless- there are a few cases where some benchmarking can be helpful- the two that I can see off the top of my head are:

- **Choosing a framework** - in a situation like yours, you might take particular benchmarks into account when you have identified several frameworks that all fulfil your exact needs and need something beyond  your immediate requirements to help you decide which one to use. Ideally, though, you would write your own benchmarks to confirm how you like working with each one- the writing would probably be more important than the benchmark.
- **Deciding how much optimisation is premature** - if you know you are using a framework that turns requests around very quickly indeed, you might not need to work on caching and other optimisations, which can save you time to focus on your actual application design rather than on infrastructure to support it. Even just having a finger-in-the-air indication as to how a framework stacks up in these types of scenario can be useful for your design choices.